# How to switch activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Now I have 3 activities, activity1, activity2 and activity3. I open the activities in order and never close any of them. So now I am in activity3, but I want to go back to activity1 and it must be the one which I opened. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start activity 1 from 3` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag:

```
Intent intent = new Intent ( this, Activity1.class );
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can I switch back to activity3 use the same way?

Comment: And in this way is the activity3's status remained there？

Comment: No only activity 1 will be dr and you need to start activity 3 again. You can override back button to show activity on back button.

Comment: What if I didn't want to close activity3?

Comment: start the activity without FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and use flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to bring the previous activity to front.

Answer (score 0):

according to [developer doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), you should use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` into the intent you want to start.

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP :
>   If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.

use `addFlags` before start back activity1.